# How to check if data connected or not in Android and ios using codenameOne

Tags: codenameone

The following code is working fine for Android Devices bt it doesn't works in ios using codenameOne.

```
public static boolean checkNetwork(){
    boolean online = false;
    String net = NetworkManager.getInstance().getCurrentAccessPoint();
    if (net == null || net == "" || net.equals(null)) {
        online = false;
    } else {
        online = true;
    }
    return online;
}
```

Note : It seems No Connection Error Even data was connected to ios device

Answer (score 1):

There is a CN1 library written by [LittleMonkey](https://github.com/littlemonkeyltd) that you can use to check connectivity. Search for `connectivity` in Codename One Extensions and download it to your project.

You can check for connection like this:

```
if (Connectivity.isConnected()) {
    //we have some connection
} else {
    // we have no connection
}
```

And you can check what type of connection

```
ConnectionState status = Connectivity.getConnectionState();
switch (status) {
    case DISCONNECTED:
        Log.p("Disconnected");
        break;
    case WIFI:
        Log.p("On Wifi");
        break;
    case MOBILE:
        Log.p("On Mobile Data");
        break;
    default:
        //shouldn't be possible
}
```

Read more about this [on GitHub](https://github.com/diamondobama/codenameone-connectivity).

Comment: FYI You can install that library from Codename One Settings -> Extensions